# Points on a projective variety modulo $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that for $n \geq 4$ we have $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ is a homogeneous polynomial. Consider a large prime $p$, and suppose that we consider points of the variety $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. If we consider non-singular points, then it is easy to see that the number of non-singular points is at most $O(p^{n-2})$, since this is a $(n-2)$-dimensional variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. Then can we say that the number of non-singular points subject to the condition that $1 \leq x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n-2} \leq \sqrt{p}$ is say $O(p^{d})$, where the bound $d$ is better than simply the measure of the box $[1, \sqrt{p}] \times \cdots [1, \sqrt{p}] \times [1, p] \times [1, p]$?

Comment: Try $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_1 - x_2$ ...

Comment: Also if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are to be coordinates on a projective variety then one cannot evaluate them to check whether $1 \leq x_1,x_2 \leq \sqrt p$, so the question would have to be reformulated in any case, even before imposing some restriction to rule out counterexamples such as $x_1-x_2$.  Maybe start by considering affine varieties in $n$-space (which have $O(p^{n-1})$ points mod $p$).

Comment: The situation I am trying to understand is how by restricting some coordinates to a small subset of possible residues modulo $p$, how it would affect the estimate for non-singular points. Intuitively it should make the bound smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we identify $\mathbf{F}_p$ with $X_p=\{0,1,\ldots, (p-1)\}\subset [0,p]$, one can probably show that for many varieties $Y/\mathbf{Z}$ in $\mathbf{A}^n$ (e.g, many hypersurfaces), the intersection $Y\cap [0,B]^n$ has not much more than the expected number $B^{n-1}$ of points, for $B$ slightly larger than $\sqrt{p}$ (e.g., $B$ about $\sqrt{p}\log p$).

The idea is to use additive characters modulo $p$ to detect the condition that an integer lies in the interval $[0,B]$, and incorporate the corresponding characters in a point-counting formula. For instance, if $Y$ is defined by $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$, you would write
$$N=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{(a,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbf{F}_p^{n+1}}{\exp(2i\pi(aF(x_1,\ldots,x_n))/p)}$$
for the total number of points on the variety modulo $p$, and then
$$
N_B=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{(a,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbf{F}_p^{n+1}}{\chi(x_1)\cdots\chi(x_n)\exp(2i\pi(aF(x_1,\ldots,x_n))/p)}
$$
for those where each $x_i$ is between $1$ and $B$, where $\chi(x)$ is the characteristic function of the interval; then write
$$
\chi(x)=\sum_{0\leq b\leq p-1}{\hat{\chi}(b)\exp(2i\pi bx/p)}
$$
by discrete Fourier analysis, and one is led to exponential sums of the type
$$
\frac{1}{p}\sum_{(a,x_1,\ldots,x_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in\mathbf{F}_p^{2n+1}}{\exp(2i\pi(aF(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+b_1x_1+\cdots+b_nx_n)/p)}
$$
which are parameterized by $(b_1,\ldots, b_n)$.

Now if you get most of these sums to be of the right order of magnitude (i.e., squareroot cancellation -- note this will fail in the example of Noam Elkies since $F$ is then linear and will cancel with some of the additively-shifted ones), you should get what I mentioned.

For examples, references and discussion of such results, I recommend the paper "A general stratification theorem for exponential sums and applications", Crelle 540 (2001), 115-166, by E. Fouvry and N. Katz, especially the discussion in Section 10.

Comment: Can anything be proved when instead of considering a cube, we consider a rectangular box... that is, the bounds for each of the $x_i$ is not identical?

Comment: Are you sure $B$ can be taken as small as $p^{1/2+\epsilon}$?  Even for a case as simple as $n=2$, $F(x_1,x_2)=x_1 x_2 - 1$ (which is not affected by the kind of degeneracy that dooms $x_1 - x_2$), the bounds on exponential sums (here Kloosterman sums) give the desired result only for $B = p^{3/4 + \epsilon}$.  (@SYX: yes, or more generally $B_1 B_2 = p^{3/2 + \epsilon}$.)

Comment: You're right; I was thinking of other problems (as in Cor. 1.4, in Katz-Fouvry) about distribution of values of polynomials.  The current problem is more like their Cor. 1.5, and I forgot that one must balance the main term with the error term...

Under suitable geometric assumptions, Fouvry-Katz get the distribution for hypersurfaces in $\mathbf{A}^n$ for $B\geq p^{1/2+1/(2n)+\epsilon}$, see (1.4) in their paper.


Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @Denis' references: results of this sort with very mild hypotheses on the variety are proved in [Fouvry's paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/fouvry.pdf) "Consequences of a result of N. Katz and G. Laumon..." $B$ has to be a fair bit bigger than $\sqrt{p},$ but there are very few hypotheses on the variety. For an example application, see Ahmadi and Shparlinksi's paper on counting matrices with restricted entries.